# Data access layer with multiple data sources

Tags: json, entity-framework, repository, data-access-layer

I have a task: I need create data access layer, which can work with multiple data sources (json files, xml files, sql server). But I just have no any idea, how it should be done.
I have tried create my own context by inheriting DBContext class (something like JsonContext), which contains paths to json files and does I/O operations, but now i think it looks kinda stupid :).
Maybe I can create interface of basic repository and implement it with each data source? Or maybe exists patterns or practices, that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad idea to take the DbContext that EntityFramework generates for you, and use that as your common base class for all of the different data sources (JsonContext inherits from DbContext).  However, the problem I see with this approach is that when you instantiate a JsonContext, it will call the constructors of the base class, DbContext, and try to connect to SQL Server, which is not what you want.

I don't know if there is an accepted pattern for doing what you're trying to do, so I think you're probably just going to have to invent your own common interface or base class that all the concrete data sources will have to implement.